# Turf.js pointsWithinPolygon works for Polygon but not FeatureCollection

Tags: javascript, turfjs

I am trying to use Turf.js to find all points within a bounding box for a FeatureCollection. According to the documentation, you can provide the function [pointsWithinPolygon](https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon) with either a Feature or a FeatureCollection of Points.

Using a modified version of the official example from the documentation, I get the following error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

```
    var locationA = turf.point([-75.343, 39.984], {
        name: 'Location A'
    });
    var locationB = turf.point([-75.833, 39.284], {
        name: 'Location B'
    });
    var locationC = turf.point([-75.534, 39.123], {
        name: 'Location C'
    });

    var collection = turf.featureCollection([
        locationA,
        locationB,
        locationC
    ]);

    var points = turf.points([
        [-80, 30],
        [-70, 30],
        [-70, 50],
        [-80, 50],
    ]);

    console.log(turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, collection)); // Doesn't work
```

Any idea what is going wrong here or what might cause the problem?
The application seems to work for a Polygon, but not for a Feature Collection.

```
var searchWithin = turf.polygon([[
    [-46.653,-23.543],
    [-46.634,-23.5346],
    [-46.613,-23.543],
    [-46.614,-23.559],
    [-46.631,-23.567],
    [-46.653,-23.560],
    [-46.653,-23.543]
]]);

console.log(turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, searchWithin)); // Works
```

Answer (score -1):

Why

```
console.log(turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, collection)); // Doesn't work
```

According to the document at

https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon

`pointsWithinPolygon(points, polygons)`

the parameters:

```
points: Point(s)
polygons: Polygon or Multipolygon
```

Your `collection` (of points) does not meet the requirement, it is just a collection of 3 points, not Polygon or Multipolygon required.

```js
// This checks if tutf is loaded?
try {
  /* Begin: put your code in this area below */
  // Points as polygon vertices
  var locationA = turf.point([-75.343, 39.984], {
    name: "Location A"
  });
  var locationB = turf.point([-75.833, 39.284], {
    name: "Location B"
  });
  var locationC = turf.point([-75.534, 39.123], {
    name: "Location C"
  });

  var poly_from_points = turf.polygon([[
    turf.getCoord(locationA),
    turf.getCoord(locationB),
    turf.getCoord(locationC),
    turf.getCoord(locationA)
  ]]);

  /* This use [x,y] directly
  var poly_from_points = turf.polygon([[      
        [-75.343, 39.984],
        [-75.833, 39.284],
        [-75.534, 39.123],
        [-75.343, 39.984]]], { name: 'poly1' });
  */

  // These are points that need to find out ...
  // ... which are inside the polygons
  var four_points = turf.points([
    [-80, 30],
    [-70, 30],
    [-70, 50],
    [-80, 50],
    [-75.55, 39.35]
  ]);

  console.log("Points inside the polygon:");

  var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(four_points, poly_from_points);
  console.log("Result:", ptsWithin);
  console.log("_End_");
  /* End of javascript code. */
} catch (err) {
  console.log("ERR! Turf is not loaded!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Turf.js/5.1.5/turf.min.js"></script>
```